# Adding jQuery to Drupal 7 site: drupal_add_js() adds but doesn't call?

Tags: javascript, navigation

I'm using jQuery accordion effects to display some information. I include the libraries:

```
    drupal_add_js('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', file);         
    drupal_add_js('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js', file);
```

Those seem to work fine, since after including them I can paste

```
jQuery(".accordion").accordion({collapsible:true,active:false});
```

into scratchpad and I get the functionality I want.

However, if I try to add it to my function like so:

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(".accordion").accordion({collapsible:true,active:false});', inline);
```

...nothing happens. I've tried some variations, such as

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready((".accordion").accordion({collapsible:true,active:false}));');
```

as well as moving the drupal_add_js() call further downstream in my code, so it appears after the elements it acts on are created and rendered.

How do I get this little snippet of code to run on my page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're most of the way there!  You just need to convert what's in your ready() to a function:

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery(".accordion").accordion({collapsible:true,active:false})});', 'inline');
```

Also, according to [docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) you should change your googleapi calls from file to 'external',

```
drupal_add_js('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', 'external');
```